# How to create a sliding dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below I have a highly inefficient code.  The code is identical across 6 rounds except for `[0:x,1:2]` where x has a x-1 change in each round, ultimately stopping at x = 8 (for variables y, x) and x = 9 (for variable t).  I do store the prediction outputs in variables `x1, x2...x6`.  See below for clear understanding.

What is the simplest concise way to write this code in a concise manner so to not repeat each step of redundant code?  I considered introducing a loop that loops through a list of variables for x - but is there something simpler or more robust?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    #round 1
        y = Macro.iloc[0:13,1:2]  
        x = Macro.iloc[0:13,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[13:14,2:21]


        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x6 = boost.predict(t)


    #round 2   
        y = Macro.iloc[0:12,1:2]
        x = Macro.iloc[0:12,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[12:13,2:21]

        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x5 = boost.predict(t)

    #round 3
        y = Macro.iloc[0:11,1:2]
        x = Macro.iloc[0:11,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[11:12,2:21]


        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x4 = boost.predict(t)

    # round 4
        y = Macro.iloc[0:10,1:2]
        x = Macro.iloc[0:10,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[10:11,2:21]


        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x3 = boost.predict(t)


    #  round 5 
        y = Macro.iloc[0:9,1:2]
        x = Macro.iloc[0:9,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[9:10,2:21]


        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x2 = boost.predict(t)

    #  round 6      
        y = Macro.iloc[0:8,1:2]
        x = Macro.iloc[0:8,2:21]
        t = Macro.iloc[8:9,2:21]


        boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
        x1 = boost.predict(t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps?.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = []


for i in range(6):
    print('round = ', i+1)
    y = Macro.iloc[0:13-i,1:2]  
    x = Macro.iloc[0:13-i,2:21]
    t = Macro.iloc[13:14-i,2:21]

    boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1,
                                           max_depth=1, random_state=0,
                                           loss='ls').fit(x, y)
    x.append(boost.predict(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(i, n):        
    y = Macro.iloc[0:i,1:2]
    x = Macro.iloc[0:i,2:21]
    t = Macro.iloc[i:n,2:21]


    boost = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=1, random_state=0, loss='ls').fit(x, y)
    x4 = boost.predict(t)
```

Comment: How will your function be called? Shouldn't it return the predicted value instead of storing it in the local variable `x4`?